# Need to know the file path of email order in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

Hello I have to changes the template of email orders it display extra value 1  with amount which is display like:

```
amount:($0,05):1
date:10-11-2015
```

In email order i am confuse by finding this value and file location

Comment: Do not understand correctly. Can you describe it more?

Comment: from admin when i confirm the booking the amount is display in email with append value 1 i want to modify this file need to know the location where the code is define for confirm booking in wocommerce.